# R Error 'Error in seq.default(min(x, na.rm = T), max(x, na.rm = T), length = length(ColRamp)) : 'from' must be a finite number'

Tags: r, numbers, colormap

I am very new to R and I have a matrix data set which I want to plot as a hexagonal colourmap. I have followed the code outlined on this page:

https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2013/11/how-to-create-hexagonal-heatmap-in-r

However, I keep getting the error message:

> Error in seq.default(min(x, na.rm = T), max(x, na.rm = T), length =
>   length(ColRamp)) :    'from' must be a finite number In addition:
>   Warning message: In seq.default(min(x, na.rm = T), max(x, na.rm = T),
>   length = length(ColRamp)) :   NAs introduced by coercion

My code is as follows:

```
    library(RColorBrewer) 
    library(fields) 

    Hexagon <- function (x, y, unitcell = 1, col = col) {
    polygon(c(x, x, x + unitcell/2, x + unitcell, x + unitcell,
        x + unitcell/2), c(y + unitcell * 0.125,
                           y + unitcell * 0.875,
                           y + unitcell * 1.125,
                           y + unitcell * 0.875,
                           y + unitcell * 0.125,
                           y - unitcell * 0.125),
      col = col, border=NA)}

      Heatmap_Matrix = as.matrix("
      3 2   3   4   5   5   5   5
      4 2   3   4   5   5   5   5
      5 0   0   4   5   5   5   5
      7 2   3   8   8   8   8   8
      1 2   3   4   5   5   5   5
      6 0   3   4   5   5   5   5
      1 2   3   9   5   5   5   5
      1 2   3   4   7   7   7   7
      8 2   4   4   5   5   5   5
      1 0   8   4   3   3   3   3
      1 0   3   5   5   5   5   5
      9 2   3   4   5   5   5   5
      1 2   4   4   5   5   5   5
      1 0   3   4   2   2   2   2
      9 2   3   4   5   5   5   5")

      x <- as.vector(Heatmap_Matrix)

       SOM_Rows <- dim(Heatmap_Matrix)[1]
       SOM_Columns <- dim(Heatmap_Matrix)[2]

       par(mar = c(0.4, 2, 2, 7))

       plot(0, 0, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlim=c(0, SOM_Columns),
       ylim=c(0, SOM_Rows), xlab="", ylab= "", asp=1)

       ColRamp <- rev(designer.colors(n=50, col=brewer.pal(9, "Spectral")))

       ColorCode <- rep("#FFFFFF", length(x)) #default is all white
       Bins <- seq(min(x, na.rm=T), max(x, na.rm=T), length=length(ColRamp))
       for (i in 1:length(x))
       if (!is.na(x[i])) ColorCode[i] <- ColRamp[which.min(abs(Bins-x[i]))]

       offset <- 0.5 
       for (row in 1:SOM_Rows) {
       for (column in 0:(SOM_Columns - 1))
       Hexagon(column + offset, row - 1, col = ColorCode[row + SOM_Rows * column])
       offset <- ifelse(offset, 0, 0.5)
       }  

       image.plot(legend.only=TRUE, col=ColRamp, zlim=c(min(x, na.rm=T), max(x, na.rm=T)))
```

I do not know much about R coding but I have been trying for days to remove the error message. It's probably something simple but I wouldn't know. I basically just copied the code from the link above.

I would be very grateful if anyone knows what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is about how you input `Heatmap_Matrix`. When I run `str(x)` I see that it read that as a long string of characters (which is what the quote marks told it to do). Separating numeric values with commas would be my normal approach, or if it's a lot of data, saving it as a tab or comma delimited text file in e.g. excel and then reading it in in R with `read.csv` or the like.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I had originally tried loading it as a txt file but that also showed the same error. I will try removing the quote marks and see if there is any other way I can load it in. I do agree that it is likely some sort of input problem as that is the only variable I have changed in the code.

Comment: Are you clear what `str` does and how to interpret it? It might be helpful to play with some very small files (e.g. a 2x2 table) to figure out a good pipeline to move from your data to R. I rarely run into issues with `read.csv` for nice arrays or `read.tsv` (actually check the name of that, it might be off) for ragged ones.

Comment: I haven't used str before. What does this function do? I will try out using a very small matrix to start with then and see if that helps.

Comment: Might be helpful to go through some tutorials/ websites like these: https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html  https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/13-supp-data-structures/